# Why I can't get session ID of Watson-assistant v2 API with curl?

Tags: curl, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, filemaker, watson-assistant

I'm trying to get session ID from Watson-Assistant API v2 using cURL function in FileMaker 17, but 500 error has occuring.
in API docs(v2), they said that the 5xx range error is internal system error that cannot be resolved by the user,  but I'm not sure whether I just only made mistake cURL command, or system problem indeed. Because I have no experience to use cURL ever.

My environment is below.

> Region: Tokyo
>
> Service Plan: Standard
>
> Skill: assigned to assistant.
>
> Preview Link of the assistant: is functioning.

I've already tried the cURL command below in FileMaker using "Insert from URL" script step.
(filemaker has special description method for using cURL, so we have to use escape by backslash in command.)

```
" -u \"apikey:{api key}\"" & 
" -X POST"
```

Target url is...

```
"https://gateway-tok.watsonplatform.net/assistant/api/v2/assistants/{my assistant id}/sessions?version=2019-02-28"
```

I want to get a json result like below.

```
{
  "session_id": "a generated session id "
}
```

but actual result is below.

```
{
    "code" : 500,
    "error" : "Error occurred while creating session"
}
```

I'm Japanese people who can't write English grammatically correct. Please forgive me if you don't understand my explanation well.
Thank you.

Comment: Your url looks ok, which suggests that the way you are passing in the rest of the information is incorrect. Or maybe the way you are passing in the assistant id. Is there any reason why you are not able to run the curl command in a terminal window? If you have an Apple Mac, then curl should already be installed.

Comment: Mr.chughts, Wow, I didn't have the idea that try it in Terminal app. I tried it, and then, it worked. After this, I fixed my cURL command in FileMaker like the command which was functioned in Terminal app. It also worked. Thank you soooo much!! Best regards,

Comment: Excuse me @chughts , I've been encountering next trouble.
after I got session id, I wanted to proceed next step, but error occured. This command worked normally in Terminal App in Mac, but in FileMaker, doesn't worked. The code is below. `curl -u \"apikey:{key}\" -X POST  -H \"Content-Type:application/json\" -d \"{\"input\" : {\"text\" : \"hello\"}}\"  \"https://gateway-tok.watsonplatform.net/assistant/api/v2/assistants/{my assistant id}/sessions/" & {session id} & "/message?version=2019-02-28\""`. and the error is below. `{"code" : 400,"error" : "Unexpected end of JSON input"}`.

Comment: if you get any insight from the code above, please let me know whatever.

Comment: The command seems correct, although I am not sure about how you need to frame the input for FileMaker - i.e. Do you need & {session_id} & and not just {session_id} and do you need \" around some of the elements like -u \" rather than -u "apikey:{key}" etc..

Comment: @timd Thank you for your advice, I got a idea from your comment, in order to no using wastefully escape character in the script. And then, it worked. I really appreciate for you. If there is something trouble occur again, help me please.